# How to decompress encrypted .enz files

Tags: archive, decompression

Until a recent reinstall of 16.04 I was able to extract encrypted .enz files (made with Cobian in Windows) with the Ubuntu archive manager. Now, following the reinstall, archive manager chokes on the encryption password with the message, "An error occurred while extracting files." I know the password I am using is correct because it works on the same file opened with Cobian Decompressor in Windows. Any suggestions about what might get me back to being able to open these files in Ubuntu (that does not involve wine)?

Comment: archive manager itself does NOT uncompress files. It uses the actual tool needed to extract ENZ. Install that and archive manager adds it to its accepted extration tools.  What was  the tool you used? ;-) I have not found one online :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIXED! The answer is the *full* 7zip.

```
sudo apt install p7zip-full
```

did the trick. See [https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/6e6f6d1b-95c3-46df-8a26-b7efd8ee4b57/entry/how_to_use_7zip_on_linux_command_line144?lang=en] is where I got the idea to try this.

Comment: Credit where credit's due department: It was Rinzwind's informative  comment that prompted me to  search for "the actual tool needed to extract ENZ." Thanks for that, Rinzwind.